# как использовать один java файл в разных проектах Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

в одном из файлов java я уже собрал много нужных функций,

и хотел бы иметь возможность дополнять и изменять его по мере необходимости из Разных проектов использующих эти функции.

как использовать один java файл в разных проектах Android Studio?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я слышал о модулях, но подробной документации для начинающих не нашел.

Comment: а почему нельзя создать объект этого класса и использовать его методы?

Comment: Экспортируйте его как jar библиотеку и подключайте куда хотите. Способ экспорта зависит от системы сборки, которую вы используете.

Comment: А вообще, не лучше бы в вашей ситуации не массивы float использовать, а написать классы с методами? У вас же ООП язык. А то выглядит как код перенесенный из C.

Comment: после множества тестов оказалось что float[] быстрее чем отдельный класс

Comment: Судя по описанию экспорта в jar я теряю возможность изменять java код из проекта. Поскольку компиляция не дает возможность дальнейшего редактирования прямо из проекта мне бы не хотелось использовать этот неудобный способ.